# Get a UITableView to not scroll and grow within a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiscrollview

I need to create a screen that is similar to the one below.  The only way I can come up with is to have a UIScrollView be the parent view.  Then have a UIImageView and UILabels for the thumbnail and main text ("All3Sports").

For the sections like the phone numbers and home page, I thought I could have a UITableView and have it simply not scroll and "grow" vertically based on it's content.  I can't figure out how to do this.  I can set it to not scroll, but then content gets clipped.  If I set it not to clip then the scroll view still thinks it's a smaller size and doesn't scroll the content.

I'm open to ideas if there's a better approach to reproducing this screen.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did something like this with a UITableView and set the table view style to UITableViewStyleGrouped but put the image & title, in your case "All3Sports", in the Header of the grouped table view and the 3 bottom buttons in the Footer.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using UITableViewStyleGrouped, with custom tableview cells for each row. The text and image for the name would be one cell type, the main, ringtone and homepage are another.  The final cell with three buttons inside it would be another.